# Centering div inside of a div & alignment of it's blocks

Tags: html, css

Well, as it is shown on the screenshot I've linked below, there's a problem with centering this div containing two Tumblr posts columns. I want to have it centered in the part of the page, where no sidebar is given. Moreover, I would like to make posts in two columns following each other without any space. IMG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLkkr.jpg

CSS:

```css
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            text-align: center;
            word-wrap: break-word; 
        }
        body #content {
            width: 900px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        }
        body #content #wrapper {
            display: inline-block;
            max-width: 900px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        body #content #wrapper #posts {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: white;
            width: 400px;
            margin: 0 15px 15px 0px;
            padding: 10px;
            float: left;
            text-align: left;
        }
        body .sidebar {
            display: table;
            width: 250px;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
        }
        body .sidebar .sidebar-inside {
            display: table-cell;
            max-width: 250px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        /* etc */

HTML:
```

```html
<!-- These two columns -->    
    <div id='content'>
    <div id='wrapper'>
    {block:Posts}
    <div id='posts'>
        {block:Photo}
            <!-- Here are posts. -->
    </div>
        {/block:Posts}
    </div>
    </div>
    
<!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class='sidebar'>
        <div class='sidebar-inside'>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Help me out, guys! Please!

Comment: please post website :)

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs It is all seen on the screenshot

Comment: Than i cannot help you, maybe render your example.. {block:Photo} (post html when page is loaded not what you make)

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs danyaiv.tumblr.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a solution (for one thing) with CSS3 Column: (and do not use mulitple times the id atrribute.. use classes.. )

```
body #content #wrapper {
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    column-count:2;
    -moz-column-gap:405px;
    -webkit-column-gap:405px;
    column-gap:405px;
}

body #content #wrapper #posts {
    <strike>float: left;</strike> /*delete this one..*/
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

**Edit:** user ask for more..

the reason is that the sidebar is position:absolute; so it does not count in space available for centering..

```
place this just behind </div> from wrapper
<div class="Gh2"></div>

.Gh2 {
    width: 250px; /*sidebar width*/
    float: right; /*place it to the right where sidebar is*/
    height: 1px; /*need some height..*/
}
```

than:

```
body #content {
    /* width: 900px;  deleted those unwanted settings*/
    /* display: inline-block; deleted those unwanted settings*/
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
```

Comment: Well, I did work at this point, but there is one more problem now: a huge gap between columns. You can see it by going to the link I've added.

Comment: @dan: -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -moz-column-gap: 0px; column-gap: 0px;  set it to zero and because post is inline-block not a block  so remove display: inline-block; from #posts

Comment: Yes! It did work out! Thank you! But is there any way to centre those columns now?

Comment: <div#content><div#wrapper></div><div.Gh2></div></div> structure (so inside div #content as last child

Comment: I'm happy that i could help

Comment: @dan feel free to ask :-)